# ArrayList is null after executing onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I have `Activity` > `Fragment` >  `RecyclerView` .

I am getting data from server in a `ArrayList` to inflate `recyclerView` in `onCreate()` of fragment.

In `recyclerView` there is `Image` with which I open camera and click photo.

But when I return after successful image capture, I get my `ArrayList` `null`

`onCreate` in  `ShipmentFragment` :

```
 ArrayList<ShipmentDetails> shipmentList;

 @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    shipmentList = getShipmentLists();
}
```

in activity's `onActivityResult` :

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPTURE_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                ShipmentFragment shipmentFragment = new ShipmentFragment();
                shipmentFragment.entryToList();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(OrderActivity.this, "Error capturing image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            break;
    }
```

`entryToList()`  in  `ShipmentFragment`:

```
public void entryToList() {
    // Here I get shipmentList null
    int size = shipmentList.size();
}
```

Comment: `onActivityResult` is in `Activity` ?

Comment: yes, it is in Activity

Comment: it should be in `fragment` as well, and get the results in `fragment's onActivityResult`, because you are creating new fragment in onActivityResult and old instance will not be accessible at that time resulting in no Data

Comment: @AbdulKawee ok, let me try

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/6147919/7835745

Comment: @AbdulKawee It worked. I have removed the onActivityResult from activity and used Fragment's insted. thank you for explanation Abdul.

Comment: Wow thats great, glad i was able to help you :) Happy coding